# VS Just-In-Time debugging won't work

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-7-x64

I have Just-In-Time debugging enabled in VS options for all code types; however, whenever a process (.NET) throws an unhandled exception, Windows just shows a "process has stopped working" window and then terminates the process; no prompt to attach the debugger. The same is happening when I'm adding a Debugger.Break() call to that process.
Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to switch off the "Automatically check for solutions" option in "Control Panel\System and Security\Action Center\Problem Reporting Settings"

Comment: Not so easy in Windows 10. [See here](https://superuser.com/questions/950997/disable-error-reporting-in-windows-10-home).